# Error message while runing a C# application in Windows 7, which previously worked under Windows Vista

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

What does this kind of an error message mean?
I have a C# form application, and it compiled well under Windows Vista, when i tried to run it under Windows 7 i get the following message. Any clue what caused this?
I used Visual Studio 2008 to develop this application

```
Description:    
  Stopped working

Problem signature:    
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3    
  Problem Signature 01: matrium.exe    
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0    
  Problem Signature 03: 4e0c494c    
  Problem Signature 04: System    
  Problem Signature 05: 2.0.0.0    
  Problem Signature 06: 4a275e22    
  Problem Signature 07: 3a97    
  Problem Signature 08: 394    
  Problem Signature 09: System.ComponentModel.Win32    
  Locale ID:    10313
```

Comment: Data your posted unfortunately give no information regarding possible causes

Comment: What kind of data do you require? this was the only message that was displayed or how should i find more information about the problem ?

Comment: The actual exception message will give useful information. If you have the source code, you're able to collect it.

Comment: The source the exception is being throwing from would be nice too.

Comment: Do you have any static constructors in your project?

Answer (score 1):

CLR20r3 is a pretty generic error message and doesn't really tell us anything useful about what might be going wrong.

Your best bet here is to hook into the AppDomain unhandled exception event and see what's going on:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(HandlerMethod);

void HandlerMethod(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if ((args.ExceptionObject is ThreadAbortException) != true)
    {
        var exception = args.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
    }
}
```